# hadoop start namenode error root account is not found

Tags: hadoop, ssh, hadoop3

when i have run `bin/hdfs namenode -format`,i want to run `sudo sbin/start-dfs.sh`,but it throw a error that `root account is not found`.

`Starting namenodes on [localhost]
ERROR: Refusing to run as root: root   account is not found. Aborting.
Starting datanodes
ERROR: Refusing to run as root: root   account is not found. Aborting.
Starting secondary namenodes [bogon]
上一次登录：日 9月 23 14:57:26 CST 2018pts/0 上
bogon: ssh: connect to host bogon port 22: Connection timed out`

Comment: You shouldn't run Hadoop using sudo. Make an actual user account for the hdfs and yarn services

Comment: Thank you.i try to do.it